# On Octobercms frontend results does't respect array order

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend, october-form-controller, october-partial

I'm using a yaml file with a repeater field to select some categories on backend.

Then on partial i use:

```
$categories = \...\..\Category::whereIn('id', $categories)->get();
$this['categories'] = $categories;
```

Then on fronted i use:

```
{% for category in categories%}
    {{ category.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Everything is working fine and i get all categories of array variable $categories in frontend. The problem is than no matter if i change the array order the result order is always the same. For example this array:

```
$categories = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

gives the same order results with this array:

```
$categories = [4, 1, 2, 5, 3];
```

Is there a way to make it respect array order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are using mysql its easy to customise order based on what order you are passing your id.

```php
$categories = [4,5,1,3];
$sortedCategories = \...\..\Category::whereIn('id', $categories)
    ->orderByRaw(\DB::raw("FIELD(id," . implode(',', $categories) .  ")"))
    ->get();
```

> it will created sort on `FIELD(id, 4,5,1,3)` assuming `$categories = [4,5,1,3]` and your records will be sorted like that.

### Client side

> Or if you are using `SQlite` then `FIELD sort is not available`. alternatively if you have `small amount of records` you can sort it `client side using collection helper method sortBy`.

```php
$category = [1,2,4,5,3];
$categories = \...\..\Category::whereIn('id', $categories)->get();
$sortedCategories = $categories
    ->sortBy(function ($item) use ($category) {
        return array_search($item->id, $category);
    });
dd($sortedCategories); // sorted based on $category = [1,2,4,5,3]
```

if any doubts please comment

Comment: I use a repeater field to create categories array. Then i change category order on repeater field by dragging. I see that array order is changed but the result is always the same. How can i sort it client side respecting repeater order? I try ->orderBy() but i can't find a way to respect repeater field order.

Comment: I posted code to sort it on client side , please check that. 2nd code

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you are ordering. Use the Laravel collections to order the array. Twig will print ascending priortizing numeral indexes. `[5,4,2,3,1]` will always come out as `[1,2,3,4,5]`. So a Laravel collection that has `[0, 1, 2]` you can use the `->sortBy` method to switch up which model instance attacked to the index.

So you might have a model that contains a name field. Your first record's name is John and your last is Adam. Twig will display John to Adam. Using the `->sortBy('name')` will display alphabetically ascending list.

```
[0=>['name'=>'John'], 1=>['name'=>'Zack'], 2=>['name'=>'Adam']] 
//Using ->sortBy('name') becomes:
[0=>['name'=>'Adam'], 1=>['name'=>'John'], 2=>['name'=>'Zack']]
```